# Nonabelian group of order 28.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Is there a nonabelian group of order 28 whose 2-Sylow subgroup is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$?

My reasoning is that by Sylow's Theorem, there is a 2-Sylow subgroup of order $4$. Since it is of order $p^2=2^2$, then this subgroup is abelian. By the fundamental theorem for finite abelian groups, this group is isomorphic to either $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Is this reasoning enough?

Comment: How could this be enough?   You haven't eliminated the case where the Sylow subgroup is non-cyclic.   To go further, you need to analyze the non-abelian groups of order $28$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are exactly two nonabelian groups of order $28$, namely the dihedral group $D_{14}$ and another group, namely the so-called dicyclic group of order $28$, which is a semidirect product of $C_7$ and $C_4$.

Now the Sylow $2$-subgroups of $D_{14}$ are not cyclic.
They are isomorphic to $C_2\times C_2$. What about the other group?

Reference: These [notes](http://www.math.drexel.edu/%7Erboyer/courses/math533_03/sylow_thm.pdf), which contain the solution to the (popular) question on the Sylow $2$-subgroups of a group of order $28$.

Comment: Thanks for the reference.

Comment: Is "$V_4$" a typo?  I'm not sure what you mean by the generalized quaternion group of order $28$, but every nontrivial semidirect product of $C_7$ and $V_4 = C_2 \times C_2$ is isomorphic to $D_{14}$, and the only other nonabelian group is what I would call the dicyclic group $C_7 \rtimes C_4$.  This is confirmed by both the notes you link and [GroupProps](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Classification_of_groups_of_order_four_times_a_prime_congruent_to_3_modulo_4).

Comment: @RaviFernando You are right - I have corrected it, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If there is, it must arise as a nontrivial semidirect product $\mathbb Z_4\ltimes \mathbb Z_7$. And indeed the map $\mathbb Z_4\to\mathbb Z_6(\cong$ $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb Z_7))$, defined by $0,2\mapsto 0$ and $1,3\mapsto 3$ is a nontrivial homomorphism, and the only such one (you just need to recall what the possible kernels are, that $4\nmid 6$, and that, under a homomorphism, the order of the image of an element divides the order of the element).